# How to automatically print the values of just updated variables

Tags: gdb

I know this could be a pipe dream, just throw it here.

So here is the code:

```
int f()
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

  for (; i < 10 && j < 100; ++i, j = i * 2) {
    i = f2();
  }
}
```

So when it comes to function f(), I can run "disp i j" and then after each single line step over, the values of i and j print out. It works fine.

But is there a global setting or some trick so that, I do not need to type the "display" command, all local variables are automatically printed ***AND*** they are printed only when their values are updated.

Another words, at the line `i = f2()`, the value of j does not print.

Comment: if you are looking for conditional printing then it is better to use print statement in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the watchponits on `i` and `j`. Like this

`(gdb) watch i`

It will automatically print the value of `i` whenever value of `i` changes

You can also print the value based upon some condition using `if<condition>`. Like this

`(gdb) watch i if j==4`

For me there is no issue in printing the value of `j` at
`i = f2();` line.